# Is there a way to stop my character going off the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a game with a character that goes to a random position whenever you click on it. Also, I made it so the game automatically goes into full-screen. However, sometimes, the character goes way off-screen and (because there are no scroll bars in full-screen) you cant get to it. The code is below.

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>
 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa Slab One' rel='stylesheet'> <!-- add the font used -->
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function move() { //move the bird
const height = screen.height;  //set the screen params
const width = screen.width;
const box = document.getElementById("bird"); //search for the bird
let randY = Math.floor((Math.random() * height) + 1);  //randomise the coords
let randX = Math.floor((Math.random() * width) + 1);

box.style.transform = `translate(${randX}px, ${randY}px)`;  //move the bird
addScore();  //add the score
}
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function getreqfullscreen(){  //full screen it. I cant really understand how it works
var root = document.documentElement
return root.requestFullscreen || root.webkitRequestFullscreen || root.mozRequestFullScreen || root.msRequestFullscreen
}
function startFullScreen() {
var pagebody = document.getElementById("main");
var globalreqfullscreen = getreqfullscreen();
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
var target = e.target
globalreqfullscreen.call(pagebody) 
}, false)
}
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var points = 0;
function addScore() {   //add the score
var pointcount = document.getElementById("scoreCount");  //get the score counter
//var points = 45;  --used for testing
points = points + 1;  //increment the points
pointcount.innerText = "score: " + points;
//pointCounter.removeChild(pointCounter.childNodes[0]); --used for an older prototype
}
/**************************************/
function startCountdown() { //initiate the timer - starts when the <body> loads
startFullScreen(); //make it full screen
var time = 9999999999999999999999;  //would be 60, but I made it infinite
setInterval(function() { //decrease every second
var timer = document.getElementById("Timer");  //get the timer
time = time - 1; //decrement the timer
timer.innerText = "time: " + time;
if(time == 0) {  //if you finished
var continuE = prompt("Would you like to restart? (type Y for yes and N for no (case sensitive)).");
if(continuE == "Y") {
window.location.reload();
} else {
history.go(-1);
}
}
},1000);
}
 </script>
 <style>
  html {
   cursor: crosshair;
   background-color: #00b0e6;
   user-select: none;
  }

  #bird {
   position: absolute;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   cursor: crosshair;
   transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  }

  #bird:hover {
   invert: 0 0 12px #ff0000;
  }

  /*
span {
height:10px;ss
width:200px;
border:5px double red;
color:#ff00ff;
background-color:#00ffff;
}
*/
  p {
   color: #ff00ff;
   background-color: #000000;
   border: 5px double red;
   height: 60px;
   width: 85px;
   margin: 10px;
   font-family: "Times New Roman";
  }

  .restartButton {
   border-radius: 999px;
   background-color: #ff00ff;
   color: #00fffff;
   border: 10px double blue;
   transition: all 1s ease-out;
   margin-left: 50%;
   margin-right: 50%;
   position: relative;
   cursor: help;
  }

  .restartButton:hover {
   border-radius: 999px;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   color: #4500fff;
   border: 10px solid red;
  }

  #scoreCount {
   color: #aff823;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
  }

  #Timer {
   color: #aff823;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 200px;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
  }

  span {
   font-family: Alfa Slab One;
  }

  #main {
   background-color: #00b0e6;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body onload="startCountdown()" id="body">
 <div id="main">
  <div id="pointCounter"><span id="scoreCount"></span><span id="Timer"></span></div>
<input type="button" value="RESTART" onclick="window.location.reload();" class="restartButton"/>
<img src="https://art.pixilart.com/81a784782ea5697.png" alt="" height="50px" width="50px" id="bird" onclick="move();">
</div>
<noscript>
YOU DO NOT HAVE JAVASCRIPT ENABLED. PLEASE ENABLE JAVASCRIPT ELSE THIS WEB PAGE WILL NOT WORK.
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Because of how stack overflow works, it doesn't go into full-screen.

P.S. I have made it infinite time, it's meant to only be 60 seconds.

Comment: You want the bird to stay within screen all the time.. is that what you mean?

Comment: @I.M.SMART, i supose the issue is here, try: `let randY = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 1);  //randomise the coords`

Comment: Yes, so you can see most of the bird

Comment: @I.M.SMART, did you checked, did my answer solve the problem?

Comment: If you do that ( I have tried) won't it still go off the screen on, lets say, a mobile phone? I tried and it _didn't_ go off the page (vertically) but only vertically - obviously

Comment: @I.M.SMART, i don't understand. Could you explain the issues what appears even if you try what i suggest?

Comment: The bird doesn't go over the entire page - the randomising doesn't let it do so. I could add a black div or something to the bottom of the page, but that would be messy. If there was a way to test the height of the page, then limit the randomising to the size of the page, then that would help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211139/discussion-between-asking-and-i-m-smart).

Comment: @I.M.SMART, please try : let randY = Math.floor((Math.random() * window.innerHeight) + 1);. Tell me if it works. And, if it solves the issue, please accept the answer